# How Avoid to load Zk Powered Logo?

Tags: css, zk

I am facing a issue may be related to ZK Icon load issue. ZK icon is getting loaded by `http` call and we have a secure site which is `https`. I tried the above overriding css property but still facing the issue. I overrided the css property in `style.css` but still icon is loading in my application. Any suggestion will be of real help. 
[Reference Link](http://zkframeworkhint.blogspot.in/2013/07/how-to-aviod-to-load-zk-powered-logo.html)
Thanks in advance

Comment: Who Vote to down ? Can you tell me What the issue in question?

Comment: Do you mean you want to block the request of ZK logo? Probably you can write a filter to do it.

Comment: Yes right i dod not want to load ZK Powered Logo in my production server

Comment: I did '.z-initing { width: 50px !important; height: 72px !important; background-image: url('../img/myImages.png') !important; } '

Comment: then just write a filter (at server side), check request uri in it, and response 404 code (or something else) if it is the request of load logo. It would be better to apply the 'correct' way that Sean mentioned below however :)

Answer (score 2):

The only **correct** way to remove the 'Powered by ZK' logo from your application is to use the PE or EE versions of ZK. Both come with a number of cool features, and neither display the logo. The logo (product promotion) is one of the things you give the ZK folks in exchange for all their hard work.

Their commercial licensing is [very competitively priced](http://www.zkoss.org/price/pricing). If you are working on an Open Source project, you can apply for a free PE or EE license!

[Commercial Licensing](http://www.zkoss.org/license/#commercial)
[ZK Open Source License (ZOL)](http://www.zkoss.org/license/#zol)

Regarding hacking the CSS, note the order in which the stylesheets are loaded. The logo is likely being displayed before ZK even loads your stylesheet.

Comment: SO we can not do its simple What about overriding CSS ?

Comment: Where there's a will, there's a way; I'm sure it can be done through CSS (or JS). However, the issue you're having is that, as you say on your block post, the ZK logo doesn't "look nice to you or your clients". Without a doubt, the best way to look good to your clients is to handle issues like this *the right way*: get yourself an official licensed copy of ZK.

Comment: SOrry but i mean how to hide that logo i do not want to show that logo to anyone